# NoClassDefFoundError error while using Selenium with java

Tags: java, selenium

I am new to Selenium and I am trying to access google.co.in. My code is

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
      String baseUrl = "https://www.google.co.in/";
      WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
      driver.get(baseUrl);
}
```

But I am getting an error which says  Exception in thread "main" `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/common/base/Function`

and I have also written two import statements after loading the appropriate jar file

```
import org.openqa.selenium.*;    
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
```

I am new to both selenium and java..So please help..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must add this library:

```
selenium-server-standalone-version.jar
```

and

```
selenium-java-version.jar
```

download here: [Selenium Downloads](http://www.seleniumhq.org/download/)